# Iterating over const_iterator

Tags: c++11, vector, const-iterator

ALL,

I have a function with the following signature:

```
void foo(const std::vector<Bar *> &myvec);
```

Inside this function I need to loop thru the members of the vector and perform some operations.

So, I tried this:

```
for( std::vector<Bar *>::const_iterator it = myvec.begin(); it < myvec.end(); ++it )
{
    // modify properties of Bar * pointer
    (*it)->SetSomeValue( baz );
}
```

however this code asserts since the iterator is constant.

Now obviously the vector is constant, which means that the function shouldn't be modifying myvec.

What's the best solution here?

Can I use const_cast here to remove constness? It would be kind of hack-ish, but if it works.

But I feel there must be a better solution.

TIA!!

Comment: @MFisherKDX, not even close. But after reading the answers there I understand what is happening. AFAIU, the parameter is not defined as const vector, but rather as const Bar * elements. Whcih means I am forced to use const iterators and therefore fails. Now, does this mean I can't use const vector (meaning that it will not be possible to add/remove elements)?

Comment: @L.F. you're not allocating any memory for your Bar pointers. Your code exhibits UB

Comment: @Igor. I am wrong. I think your error is elsewhere. Possibly due to an invalid pointer.

Comment: @Igor What do you mean by "this code asserts?" [Your code compiles fine.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uROqKPzQmor7TF1u) Which compiler do you use?

Comment: @MFisherKDX I'm sorry. Now it should be fine.

Comment: @L.F., code compiles fine, but throws an exception `vector iterator not incrementable`.

Comment: @Igor Again, which compiler do you use?

Comment: @L.F., MSVC 2017.

Comment: @Igor Hmm ... seems the error is at somewhere else. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @L.F., I tried to reproduce it with the MCVE and failed. Definitely looks like something else happens. Sorry for the noise and its time for debugging. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `myvec.cbegin()` method instead of `myvec.begin()`, to ensure that you are not modifying the object the iterator points to.
Of course, for `myvec.end()`, use `myvec.cend()` accordingly.

The iterator itself doesn't need to be a const_iterator, in the contrary, you want to modify the objects it gives you - `set_...()` sounds like a non-const activity.

Comment: didn't help. I get the message "vector iterator not incrementable". Also, check my edit.

Comment: If I don't use const_iterator I get the compiler error: `error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>' to 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>'.`. So I have to use it, since the vector is passed as const reference.